# where can i find open source projects for silverlight to contribute to?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am a college going student and we have to submit one project after 6 months. I am good in Silverlight (using C#) and Sql Server . Can anybody tell me where can i find good open source projects in Silverlight preferably database oriented so that i can contribute to that project and on the other hand learn a lot from other smart developers.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.codeplex.com

---

Please mark as an answer if it answers your question

Comment: I wish you will enjoy your life developing in the site :D